# Android + Volley com conector PHP retorna erro!

Tags: php, sql-server, android-studio, conexão, volley

Estou tentando conectar e enviar um cadastro, via connector PHP, da minha aplicação Android para o SQL Server no computador local. Está retornando "Erro!", pois parece que o Volley não vê o connector, ou algo assim. Poderiam me ajudar no que estou errando?

```
public class Cadastro extends AppCompatActivity{
EditText txtNome, txtEmail, txtSenha, txtRepeteSenha;
Button btnCadastrar;
ProgressBar progressBar;
ConnectionClass connectionClass;

String url = "http://localhost/cadastro.php";
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro);
    connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
    txtNome = findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtEmail = findViewById(R.id.mail);
    txtSenha = findViewById(R.id.key);
    txtRepeteSenha = findViewById(R.id.key_again);
    btnCadastrar = findViewById(R.id.cadastrar);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    btnCadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String nome, email, senha;
            nome = txtNome.getText().toString();
            email = txtEmail.getText().toString();
            senha = txtSenha.getText().toString();
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Cadastro.this);

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Cadastro.this);
                            alertDialog.setTitle("Resposta do servidor:");
                            alertDialog.setMessage("Resposta: " + response);
                            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    txtNome.setText("");
                                    txtEmail.setText("");
                                    txtSenha.setText("");
                                }
                            });
                            AlertDialog alertDialog2 = alertDialog.create();
                            alertDialog2.show();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(Cadastro.this, "Erro!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("nome", nome);
                    params.put("email", email);
                    params.put("senha", senha);
                    return params;
                }
            };
            queue.add(stringRequest);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O aparelho (emulador) não consegue se conectar porque você precisa inserir o IP ao invés de "localhost" pois no "localhost" o comando vai tentar fazer uma conexão interna no "celular" (emulador) e não no servidor.

Altere:

```
String url = "http://localhost/cadastro.php";
```

Para:

```
String url = "http://999.000.0.00/cadastro.php"; // por exemplo
```

**Como recupero esse IP?**

Digite `ipconfig` no cmd (windows) e ele irá trazer vários endereços. Eu uso o IPv4:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Respondi me baseando nesta parte da pergunta também:

> [...]pois parece que o Volley não vê o connector[...]

Comment: Algo que somente a prática traz. Algo simples mas não pensado por alguém iniciante como eu. Muito obrigado. Eu troquei e funcionou, mas não sabia o porquê de ter dado certo. Agora eu entendi a razão. 
Agora vou atrás do cadastro.php, que está dando problema, caso você puder ajudar, agradeço. 
No final, quando terminar o projetinho,  coloco todo o código por aqui.

Comment: @PauloLara tranquilo... Aprove a resposta se ela estiver correta.

Comment: @PauloLara o seu problema com relação ao insert é bem simples de resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Troquei o "localhost" pelo IP e funcionou a conexão e a busca, entretanto ainda não consigo inserir dados no SQL Server. Eis meu código abaixo:

```
<?php
include_once "conexao.php";

$username = "";   
$email = "";    
$password = ""; 
if(isset($_POST['nome'])){    
    $username = $_POST['nome'];   
}
if(isset($_POST['email'])){    
    $email = $_POST['email'];    
}
if(isset($_POST['senha'])){    
    $password = $_POST['senha'];    
}
if(!empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($email)){
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO Usuario (nome, email, senha) VALUES ('".$_POST['nome']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['senha']."')";
}
include_once "busca.php";
?>
```

Comment: Olá Paulo, isto não responde a sua pergunta. Você escreveu em um lugar de respostas. Aconselho você a criar uma nova pergunta sobre o problema em específico que é a inserção.

Comment: A sua pergunta refere-se ao problema de conexão entre o android e o php.

Comment: ok. Deixa pra mim, crio um novo post aqui. Agradecido até aqui.